# Access public shared Calender in Windows phone C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, calendar

I am developing windows phone 8 app. on the calendar topic.
I have shared public calendar on `outlook.com` and I want to sync that in my windows phone calendar through my app. how to do that?? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the [Outlook.com API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826535.aspx), in order to sync or work on with the `Calender`. Below are some of the features, which you could do with the help of API.

- Reading calendar properties
- Deleting calendars
- Creating calendars
- Updating calendar properties
- Subscribing to public calendars

But I would suggest you to go through the [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx) before you start working on with the API.

Comment: i have searched all this links,
I have implemented live sdk  in my app user can login through siging button control. but I confused at how to add my calendar link into the code showed on this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826523.aspx#cal_cs 
there is code for subscribing public calendar. please show me where I have to put my calendar link.